# Implementing cascading DropDownList binding in a asp.net detailsview templated control

Tags: asp.net, detailsview, cascadingdropdown

I have two dropdown lists inside an asp.net detailview "PlantingHatchery" and "CatalogNames". The results of the first determines the values in the second. The first fills just fine but not the second. I have looked tried a several suggestions but none work for me. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the pertinent code:

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="dvSMasterCurrentYear" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" align="center" DataKeyNames="SMasterid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        Height="50px" Width="437px" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True" AllowPaging="True" insertcommand =" Insert Into [SMasterCurrentYear}
        ([HatcheryCodePlant],[CatalogNo],[DataPlant],[TimePlant],[SpeciesCode],[BroodYear],[SizeCode],[MethodCode],[Length], [PoundFish],[NumberPlanted],[NumberPerLB],[HaulMort],
        [License], [ActSites], [HatcheryCodeRear],[Comments],[H20Temp],[ConsOfficer],[TankTemp],[Marks],[Raceway])
        Values (@HatcheryCodePlant, @CatalogNum, @DataPlant, @TimePlant, @SpeciesCode, @BroodYear, @SizeCode, @MethodCode, @Length, @PoundFish, @NumberPlanted, @NumberPerLB, 
        @HaulMort, @License, @ActSites, @HatcheryCodeRear, @Comments, @H20Temp, @ConsOfficer, @TankTemp, @Marks, @Raceway) " Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#FFCC99" Font-Size="Medium" DefaultMode="Insert">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#99FFCC" />

enter code here

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Planting Hatchery">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPlantHatch" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HatcheryCodePlant")%>' Visible = "true"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                   <insertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPlantingHatchery" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetPlantingHatchery()%>' 
                        DataTextField="HatcheryNamePlant" DataValueField="HatcheryCodePlant" width= "150" AppendDataBoundItems="true"> 
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                 </insertItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Water Body Name">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStreamName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CatalogNo")%>' Visible = "true"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                 <insertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCatalogName" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetCatalogNames()%>' 
                        DataTextField="StreamName" DataValueField="CatalogNo" AppendDataBoundItems="true"> 
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                       <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsWaterBody" runat="server" TypeName="StreamName"
                        SelectMethod="GetCatalogNames">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <%--<asp:Parameter Name="HatcheryCodetName"  Type="string" />--%>
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="HatcheryCodePlant" Type="Int32" ControlID="ddPlantingHatchery" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                </insertItemTemplate>enter code here
```

Code Behind:

Private Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) Handles dvSMasterCurrentYear.ItemInserting

Dim ddPlantHatch As DropDownList = TryCast(view.FindControl("ddPlantingHatchery"), DropDownList)
            e.Values.Add("HatcheryCodePlant", ddPlantHatch.SelectedValue)

Dim ddCatNum As DropDownList = TryCast(view.FindControl("ddCatalogName"), DropDownList) e.Values("HatcheryCodePlant") = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, DetailsView).FindControl("ddPlantingHatchery"), DropDownList).SelectedValue

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Provided your GetCatalogNames method is working properly, all you may need to do is add `autopostback="true"` to your first dropdown.

Also, your codebehind method is firing during ItemInserting, which is the default value in this case. But you may not need it.

If that doesn't work, you should set your method to fire `OnSelectedIndexChanged` of your first drop down. To do this:

Add this to your first drop down:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPlantingHatchery" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetPlantingHatchery()%>' 
                    DataTextField="HatcheryNamePlant" DataValueField="HatcheryCodePlant" width= "150" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddPlantingHatchery_indexchanged"> 
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

then add this method to the CodeBehind:

```
Public Sub ddPlantingHatchery_indexchanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ddCatNum As DropDownList = TryCast(dvSMasterCurrentYear.FindControl("ddCatalogName"), DropDownList)
    ddCatNum.SelectedValue = TryCast(dvSMasterCurrentYear.FindControl("ddPlantingHatchery"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
End Sub
```

This sample method will simply set the SelectedValue of ddCatNum to the SelectedValue of ddPlant. Of course, you can change this to instead grab the values you've defined in your ObjectDataSource method.

Another approach: Add `autopostback="true"` to your first dropdown, and change your GetCatalognames() function to return a different value based on postback, something like this:

```
    Public Function GetCatalogNames() As DataSet
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim ddPlantHatch As DropDownList = TryCast(dvSMasterCurrentYear.FindControl("ddPlantingHatchery"), DropDownList)

        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT StreamName, CatalogNo, " _
                                      + "HatcheryNamePlant, HatcheryCodePlant, " _
                                      + "LLID FROM vwStockingWatersByHatchery " _
                                      + "where HatcherCodePlant = " + ddPlantHatch.SelectedValue _
                                      + " Order By StreamName", myConnection)
        Dim dsWaterBody As New DataSet()
        ad.Fill(dsWaterBody, "Catalog")
        Return dsWaterBody
    Else


        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT StreamName, CatalogNo, " _
                           + "HatcheryNamePlant, HatcheryCodePlant, " _
                           + "LLID FROM vwStockingWatersByHatchery " _

                           + "Order By StreamName", myConnection)
        Dim dsWaterBody As New DataSet()
        ad.Fill(dsWaterBody, "Catalog")
        Return dsWaterBody
    End If


End Function
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The code behind gives me the correct value. however, this value is not being passed to the second drop down list which needs to be filtered.

Comment: I use this to fill the second drop down (ddCatalogNames) in the code behind: Public Function GetCatalogNames() As DataSet

        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT StreamName, CatalogNo, HatcheryNamePlant, HatcheryCodePlant, LLID FROM vwStockingWatersByHatchery Order By StreamName", myConnection)
        Dim dsWaterBody As New DataSet()
        ad.Fill(dsWaterBody, "Catalog")
        Return dsWaterBody

    End Function    and this seams to filling the list when the page loads

Comment: The problem appears to be when the page loads all my "Get functions" run so when the page appears all drop downs are already loaded. How do I reload the Public Function GetCatalogNames and bind to the "ddCatalogName" after the ddPlantingHatchery_indexchanged runs? thank you for your help.